# Getting error: read ECONNRESET when trying to use nodemailer with Hover.com email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm relatively new to node.js for server development and definitely new to nodemailer, but it seems like a great option for my needs. I have it working with a gmail account as a test, but I've been trying to convert it to use an email address through Hover.com, but I'm getting an error: read ECONNRESET. I've triple-checked all of my parameters (host, port, user, pass, etc.) and everything looks okay and their help hasn't been able to help me yet either, so I thought I'd ask here.

My coffeescript for creating the transport is below:

```
transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
  host: "mail.hover.com"
  secureConnection: true
  port: 465
  auth: {
    user:
    pass:
}})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a similar question on [nodemailer on github](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/170) and someone was able to help me there by indicating that it might be an issue in the TLS library of Node v0.10.x and that I could address it by changing my options to be:

```
{
    host: "mail.hover.com"
    secureConnection: true
    port: 465
    auth: {
        user: "---"
        pass: "---"
    }
    tls: {
        secureProtocol: "TLSv1_method"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and have been trying to fix it for **hours**.  The above answer helped me find the solution, but at least in my case it wasn't because I needed to specify a protocol. I had set up the object wrong, and put `user:` and `pass:` directly in the configuration object, rather than in their own `auth:` subobject.

I was doing this:

```js
const carrier = createTransport({
   host: 'mail.privateemail.com',
   port: 465,
   user: 'someone@somewhere.net',
   pass: 'my password'
});
```

...and fixed it like this, adding in the `auth: {}` object:

```js
const carrier = createTransport({
   host: 'mail.privateemail.com',
   port: 465,
   auth: {
      user: 'someone@somewhere.net',
      pass: 'my password'
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was with my wifi. I was using a public wifi and as soon as I switched to my personal network, things were working fine.